# Are advice/recommendation questions fair game on this site?

Tags: discussion, beta, site-topic

Are questions [such as the one I asked here](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/49/which-tools-would-you-recommend-for-use-when-drafting-monitoring-and-reporting-o) fair game for this site?

Comment: I asked a similar question and I was unsure about it too.

Comment: I think it's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to the question I asked:  [Is this site about Objective questions or Subjective questions? Can the site survive accepting both?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/is-this-site-about-objective-questions-or-subjective-questions-can-the-site-sur)

My question was whether or not the questions being asked can be subjective or must they be purely objective.

I spent some time on Programmers StackExchange, and I found the subjective, advice/recommendation questions to be very helpful.  Project Management is a subjective field.  The rules aren't always 100% black and white, and the definition of a project manager can be drastically different from company to company.

Therefore, I support these type of questions and encourage people to ask them.

With that said, as per Robert Cartaino's observation about the questions being asked, we should do what we can to avoid **beginner** questions so that we attract professionals when the site goes public.