# Is asking for basic PM recommendations or advice on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I had a look at [this](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-advice-recommendation-questions-fair-game-on-this-site) but since the linked example seems to be closed, I thought it would be best to clarify.

I am totally new to PM, and am looking for basic recommendations for specific PM techniques/methodologies to follow when managing my team. Would a question providing a detailed description of the scenario and asking for recommendations be on-topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question and answer you reference is old and possibly outdated, but as long as you're asking things that don't require an entire book to answer, are providing plenty of detail about your problem, what you've tried, why the problem exists, etc, then there's a good chance you'll not only get great answers but also compile information that will help others as well.

To clarify, stay away from broad, extremely open ended questions like: "Can anyone give me some advice?"  Make sure you're asking something specific, as it's easier to vote the best answers to the top when there's a specific problem to be solved.

In a way, everyone is asking because they have some kind of question or problem they need help with, but it's all about wording the question so it's clear what you're asking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, [my question is up](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9722/what-should-be-the-methodology-followed-by-a-research-and-development-project). If it is too broad, feel free to remove whatever portions necessary, as I would prefer to receive some advice rather than none :)